# jumbotron with centered text on the left and image on the right

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to vertically and Horizontally center the list-group to the left of the image in the below code.

```
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <ul class="list-group center-list">
                        <li class="list-group-item">something here</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">something here</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">something here</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>                              
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <img src="images/ModelBack.png" class="pull-right">
                </div>               
            </div>
```

I created the center-list class and have tried following a number of examples with similar questions, but my CSS is apparently lacking.

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h1>Big Test</h1>
                <h2>Little Test</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <img src="img.jpg" />
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are missing a closing tag on jumbtron maybe that is the problem,

```
<div class="jumbotron">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <ul class="list-group center-list">
                        <li class="list-group-item">something here</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">something here</li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">something here</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>                              
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                   <img src=""></img>
                </div>               
            </div>
</div>
```

try now ;)

Comment: if you are having problem with image width, just add it a class and put width 100%, it will be 100% width of you col